# Running several database instances on a single SQL Azure database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm running 3 web apps (for different customers) which each run a separate database instance. Two apps need a database with less than 2GB storage each, and the third app requires about 10GB of storage.

Looking at the [SQL Azure database plans](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/), I can use the "Basic" plan for the first two, but I need to get the Standard S0 for the third. This gives me up to 250GB of storage, which leaves a lot of excess capacity. Is there a way I can utilize the S0 database for my other two apps while still maintaining separate logical database instances?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question at all.

Comment: no you can't and do that.Databases are constrained by DTU's in azure,so you will have to look at this factor first

Comment: @TheGameiswar I don't see the relevance of DTU. The question was about creating multiple logical databases within a single database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can - this is called Azure Elastic Pools
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool

Comment: Elastic Pools may not solve the problem completely. All databases in an elastic pool are of same size. What they share amongst them are the eDTU. Bigger sized database does not necessarily mean more load on the database.

Comment: You can set individual limits on databases in a pool though

Comment: Can you share a link for that please?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a programming question strictly, but it would influence how you connect to your database. You could use an [elastic pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool), which the other answer referenced. Another option would be to create a table for each and give permissions only on the applicable table for each application login within an S0. There may even be other approaches to solving this problem - like [row level security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx).

Really, you're considering moving from a single tenant to a multi-tenant model: [here's a resource that examines this for SaaS built on SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-patterns-multi-tenancy-saas-applications).